# How to determine bounds for variables for an underdetermined linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I want to determine bounds of variables of a system of linear equations which is an underdetermined system. I illustrate with a simple example.

For instance, considering a small system --

x+y+z = 10      ----- (1)

x+y+k = 20      ----- (2)

z+n = 5         ----- (3)

Considering, each variables to non-negative, we can infer the bounds for some variables and linear combination of others from the above system of 3 equations:

from (3) -- 0 <= z <= 5  and 0 <= n <= 5     -----(4)

from (1) and (3) -- 5 <= x+y <= 10      -----(5)

from (2) and (5)  --    10 <=  k <= 20    -----(6)

It could be done manually since the system is small, if the system is large having 100 variables then it would be difficult to track down the bounds manually. Is there any systematic procedure or algorithm to do it?

Also, above illustration shows loose bounds? Is there a way to find tight bounds, w.r.t. to the solution with minimum norm?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting a "box" (lower and upperbound on each variable) is to loop over all variables and do a minimization and maximization step, I.e. something like:

[image]

We collect the optimal value (level) of $z$ in a reporting parameter **box**. When we display **box** we see:

[image]

Here a blank means zero. I get tighter values for $k$ than you do. I actually use this kind of loop sometimes to get really tight bounds needed to calculate good big-$M$ values in mixed-integer programming models and in some multi-criteria models. So this algorithm is not as stupid as it looks.

High-performance LP and MIP solvers may do some bound tightening inside the presolve step. These presolvers are quite sophisticated pieces of software.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin for your response. I appreciate it. Which software did you use to run the above algorithm?

Comment: GAMS with Cplex as solver.